# Pandas Apply function referencing column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

I'm trying to create a new column that contains all of the assortments (Asst 1 - 50) that a SKU may  belong to. A SKU belongs to an assortment if it is indicated by an "x" in the corresponding column.

The script will need to be able to iterate over the rows in the SKU column and check for that 'x' in any of the ASST columns. If it finds one, copy the name of that assortment column into the newly created "all assortments" column.

After one Liner:

[image: All Assortments populated]

I have been attempting this using the df.apply method but I cannot seem to get it right.

[image: Picture of Data]
[image: Roughly the desired output (with correct ASSTs of course)]

```
def assortment_crunch(row):
    if row == 'x':
        
df['Asst #1'].apply(assortment_crunch):
```

my attempt doesn't really account for the need to iterate over all of the "asst" columns and how to assign that column to the newly created one.

Comment: Do you know in advance how many Asst # columns there will be?

Comment: yes! there will always be a max of 50. Sometimes all won't be populated but the sheet will always extend out to 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a super fast ("vectorized") one-liner:

```
asst_cols = df.filter(like='Asst #')
df['All Assortment'] = [', '.join(asst_cols.columns[mask]) for mask in asst_cols.eq('x').to_numpy()]
```

Explanation:

- `df.filter(like='Asst #')` - returns all the columns that contain `Asst #` in their name
- `.eq('x')` - exactly the same as `== 'x'`, it's just easier for chaining functions like this because of the parentheses mess that would occur otherwise
- `to_numpy()` - converts the mask dataframe in to a list of masks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way, but you can try this.

Instead of `apply`ing to the column, `apply` to the whole DF to get access to the row. Then you can iterate through each column and build up the value for the final column:

```py
def make_all_assortments_cell(row):
  assortments_in_row = []

  for i in range(1, 51):
    column_name = f'Asst #{i}'
    if (row[column_name] == 'x').any():
      assortments_in_row.append(row[column_name])

  return ", ".join(assortments_in_row)

df["All Assortments"] = df.apply(make_all_assortments_cell)
```

I **think** this will work though I haven't tested it.

Comment: @richardec thanks for the edit! What is the effect of `.any` here?

Comment: Because when you run something like `row[column_name] == 'x'`, you don't get a True/False value like you might expect. Instead, you get a "mask", which is a Series object the same length as `row[column_name]`, where each value is True if it's `x`, False otherwise. `.any()` returns True if there are one more True values in the mask, False if there are none. :)